# Invalid XML Character in a Word 2007 (docx) document

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2007, xml

I've written a Word 2007 document and now I can't open it.

The error I get is:
The file ... cannot be opened because there are problems with the contents.
Details: Illegal xml character.
Location: Part: /word/header3.xml, Line:2 Column:1511

Any idea how I can recover the file?

Thanks,
Sagee.

Comment: And what character is on this position?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem myself.  Download OpenOffice from Sun.  Open it and then save it to a different file. It worked for me . . . The other option is that there are various vendors selling solutions to correct corrupt .doc and .docx files.  This solution was free.  http://www.openoffice.org/ . . .